# How configure virtual keyboard in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

In an data entry application in Windows 8, the user uses massively the virtual keyboard. I need to optimize the data entry.
Now, when an user enters in a field, the virtual keyboard appears. How can I configure the keyboard to show only numbers or numbers+letters from my app?

Some fields are numeric, then letters are not necessary.

I would like to configure the keyboard for each field in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the InputScope on the textbox.

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define different [input scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue) for your text boxes.